# Mathematical notation for repeating an equation

Tags: roots

I wanted to write a way of calculating a square root of a number in LaTeX. Unfortunately, as a beginner in this sphere, I do not know what math symbol means to repeat the process. To make it clear, here is my equation for finding a square root of a variable `k`

$$ \sqrt k = \frac{(n + \frac{k}{n})}{2} $$

After each calculation, a specific result is put instead of variable n, i.e:
$$ \sqrt 5 = \frac{(5 + \frac{5}{5})}{2} = 3$$
$$ \sqrt 5 = \frac{(3 + \frac{5}{3})}{2}  \approx 2.\overline{33} $$
$$ \sqrt 5 = \frac{(2.\overline{33} + \frac{5}{2.\overline{33}})}{2} \approx 2.23796 $$
$$ \sqrt 5 = \frac{(2.23796 + \frac{5}{2.23796})}{2} \approx 2.23606 $$
$$ \sqrt 5 = \frac{(2.23606797 + \frac{5}{2.23606797})}{2} \approx 2.23606797$$
$$ \sqrt 5 \approx 2.23606797... $$

FYI my English is not that good when explaining something, especially if it is Maths, so expect some weird or false vocabulary here and there...

Comment: What you have here is a recurrence relation, that is, an inductively defined sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do not do that**, instead define a sequence $(u_n)_n \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ with
$$u_0 = x_0 = k$$
$$u_{n+1} = f(u_n) = f^n (u)$$
with $f(x) = \frac{x^2 + k}{2x}$.

Show that $u_n \rightarrow \sqrt{k}$ and it will be much cleaner.

For that show that $\sqrt{k}$ is a fixed point of $f$ and that your sequence is either decreasing or increasing wether you have $x_0 > \sqrt{k}$ or not

Comment: Beware, here $f^n$ means $f \circ f \circ \cdots \circ f$, with $n$ times $f$ writen

Comment: Thank You! I will try to understand what You wrote, as my math knowledge is still low, such that I still have not learned trigonometry at my high school. :)

Comment: I suggest you focus first on learning more basic things then